# Received memory pressure event and App crashed may be because of background image size

Tags: ios, image, memory, out-of-memory

I am having seven view controllers. Each of them is loaded inside the navigation controller. First one being viewController1 and the last one being viewController7. So viewController1 will be pushed to navigation controller first, then viewController2 and the viewController3 and so on. Each of the view controllers is having dedicated tasks. Now Each of the view controllers is using a background image. The Background image is too large(30 MB).

When I push viewController1 the app becomes little slower, after pushing viewController2 again the app becomes slower. After viewController6 is pushed I am getting below logs and then the app is crashing

> received memory pressure event 16 vm pressure 0

My question is: is the above crash is happening because of the large image in single view controller or large image in multiple view controllers piling on one other in the navigation controller

I have added below code:

```
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    }
```

But no luck

Since Navigation controller is iOS provided feature, Cant it manages its multiple view controllers in such a way not to throw such memory pressure warning and crash.

How Do I Handle such situations without decreasing the background image size?

Comment: Why not compress the background images? Or remove the background images when the next view controller gets pushed onto the stack?